# C# Call method on non-generic list of generic classes

Tags: c#, generics

My main class `Computer` interacts with a number of external systems and currently has the logic for getting/updating their info crammed into it.

I want to move the logic for each system to it's own separate class and i've been able to part of the way there but i'm having trouble calling a method on them.

I've only just recently started playing around with generics so this is probably badly written code, apologies for your eyes in advance.

These are my `System` classes

```
public class System
{
    public string Name { get;set; }
}

public class System<T> : System
{
    public virtual T GetData() => default(T);
    public virtual void UpdateData() {}
}

public interface ISystem<T>
{
    T GetData();
    void UpdateData();
}
```

These are the systems i've created using the `System` classes:

```
public class ComplexSystem : ISystem<RegistryKey>
{
    public string GetData() => MethodThatGetsRegistryData();
    public bool UpdateData() => MethodThatUpdatesRegistry();
}

public class IntSystem : ISystem<int>
{
    private int value = 9;
    public int GetData() => this.value;
    public void UpdateData()
    {
        this.value = 3;
    }
}

public class StringSystem : ISystem<string>
{
    private string value = "hello";
    public string GetData() => this.value;
    public void UpdateData()
    {
        this.value = "updated";
    }
}
```

and this is how i'm trying to use the whole thing:

```
public class Computer
{   
    public List<System> AssociatedSystems = new List<System>();

    public Computer()
    {
        this.AssociatedSystems.Add(new System<ComplexSystem> {Name="ComplexSystem"});
        this.AssociatedSystems.Add(new System<IntSystem> {Name="IntSystem"});
        this.AssociatedSystems.Add(new System<StringSystem> {Name="StringSystem"});
    }

    public void UpdateDataWhenComputerIsChanged()
    {           
        // is it possible to loop through them and call UpdateData on each one without know what generic they are?
        foreach (var associatedSystem in this.AssociatedSystems)
        {
            // something like...
            associatedSystem.UpdateData();
        }
    }
}
```

Which results in

> System does not contain a definition for UpdateData() and no extension method could be found

I'm not married to the code above so if there's a better way of doing it i'm all for learning. I'm essentially looking for a way to have a list of classes that contain data logic (like `GetData()` and `UpdateData()`) so i don't have to put that logic into my main class (`Computer`)

Comment: `UpdateData` does not live in `System`, it resides in `System<T>` or `ISystem<T>`

Comment: @TheGeneral You are correct, however if i change the list to `List<System<IntSystem>>` then i can't put any other systems in there, do you know of a way i can interact with `System<T>` through `System`? Or would you code the same situation a different way?

Comment: unbelieveable, I was  just about to write my own question on SO, when your post came rushing in. almost 90 % of our problems are similar, so that I could solve it from your question :) thank you for writing it, and having almost the same thoughts as me :D, it's a pitty that I cannot upvote twice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So function `UpdateData` does not exist in `System` and that is why you cant call it. I would suggest introducing an `ISystem` interface and put `Name` (if you need it) and `UpdateData` in that and let the generic `ISystem<T>` interface inherit from that.

```
public interface ISystem
{
    string Name {get;set;}
    void UpdateData();
}

public interface ISystem<T> : ISystem
{
    T GetData();
}

public class Computer
{
    public List<ISystem> AssociatedSystems = new List<ISystem>();
    .....
    foreach (var associatedSystem in this.AssociatedSystems)
    {
        associatedSystem.UpdateData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Or i'm guessing it can be just moved to `System`, it looks base enough for that. however interfaces seem the better way here,. upvote

Comment: @TheGeneral It is usually more flexible to work with interfaces, especially when you need to do unit tests and create fakes from them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are multiple ways to do this. The ones that I can think of are:

1. Type checking each `System` in the loop
2. Adding a `Type` property to system
3. Adding a `UpdateData(object)` or `UpdateData(SomeHighLevelType)`

If you need more help please specify the nature of your systems. Are they limited to some specific types or you want is extendable for ever and how much speed critical is your project and I can elaborate more